# retrieve the tweets of the followers of a specified user using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to retrieve the tweets of the followers of a specified user(Ex: Narendra Modi) using Tweepy. I have got all the followers and printing their names. Could you guys help me out how to retrieve their tweets as well??

Here is how I am getting the followers:

```
import tweepy
import time

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


if(api.verify_credentials):
    print 'We sucessfully logged in'

users = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="PMOIndia").items()


while True:
    try:
        user = next(users)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60*15)
        user = next(users)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print "@" + user.screen_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get tweets using screen name with `user_timeline` method. After you collect the users, you can collect their tweets with the following.

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user.screen_name).items()
```

I advice you to not use screen name. Since it could change in time. Use user_id instead.